# Implicit conversion from Array to WrappedArray does not happen when pattern matching

Tags: arrays, scala

In this example:

```
scala> val a: Seq[Int] = Array(1,2,3)
a: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)
```

Implicit conversion happens, and `Array` is converted to `WrappedArray` that extends `Seq`, as explained here: [Arrays Scala Doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html)

but here:

```
object MyObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val a = Array(1,2,3)
    // val a: Seq[Int] = Array(1,2,3) if added explicitly works

    val result = a match {
      case Seq(
      first,
      second,
      third
      ) => (first, second, third)
    }
    println(result)
  }
}
```

The code fails with:

```
Error:(9, 15) scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Seq[A]
 required: Array[Int]
      case Seq(
```

The implicit conversion does not happen, Why?

Comment: As a pragmatic solution, you can always `toSeq` your array. The `toSeq` method will not construct a new collection, so it will just wrap the array. Source: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Array.html#toSeq:Seq[A]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burak Emir gave a rationale for the language design decision of disallowing implicit conversions in pattern matching (the following is quoted from [www.scala-archive.org](http://www.scala-archive.org/implicit-conversions-and-pattern-matching-td1986793.html)):

> 1) Type checking patterns relies on static information (like everywhere 
>   else in the compiler). In the case of patterns, an "expected type" is 
>   propagated down, in order to type variable binding patterns and more 
>   generally verify that the pattern is something that makes sense. The 
>   expected type starts, of course, with the scrutinee (aka the selector 
>   expression aka what is matched upon).
>
> 2) The translation of pattern matching uses (almost) every means 
>   possible to avoid redundant type tests. This means, that the cases 
>   present in the source code get "compressed" into a sort of decision tree 
>   diagram. This later gets translated to code.
>
> Enter implicit conversions. Having the scrutinee be of a different type 
>   then the patterns means we cannot make use of expected type in patterns. 
>   Consequently, we would have to type check patterns independently of the 
>   type of the scrutinee.
>
> This alone might still be feasible (careful here, who can foresee hairy 
>   interactions with sequence patterns etc). We could say, patterns have a 
>   type independent of the expected type, and type checking will see 
>   whether the type of the scrutinee complies with the pattern types 
>   (possibly after applying some implicit conversion).
>
> But this turns out to be a non-specification.

```
implicit def fbTypeToFoo ... 
implicit def fbTypeToBar ... 

fb match { 
  case Foo(...) => 
  case Bar(...) => 
}
```

> What seems to really be needed is to apply the views "by need", meaning 
>   "inside" the pattern match.
>
> This clashes with the present algorithm doing task 2). In presence of 
>   implicit conversions, the task of pattern matching is in fact pushed one 
>   level deeper, as the outermost pattern will always match (there's a 
>   conversion after all). This is quite annoying to implement and to 
>   specify, because patterns with and patterns without implicit conversion 
>   from the scrutinee type might be mixed, like in

```
implicit def FooToBar... 
myFoo match { 
  case Foo(...) 
  case Bar(... ) 
  case Foo( ...) 
}
```

> The assumption that a top-level "Foo" would never enter the "Bar" case 
>   is now invalid (there's a conversion after all). One basically loses all 
>   hope of optimizing for the outermost level. While the current matcher 
>   would join the remainder of patterns 1 and 3, a hypothetical matcher 
>   with implicit calls could not be designed to do so, as it would violate 
>   the first match policy.